# calculating screwpiles requirement in clay ground

Tags: foundation, outdoor, the-netherlands

Does anyone know a good way of calculating screw-pile requirements in clay ground? I'm in the Netherlands and this old seafloor so carrying soil type is going to be at least 10m deep before it there is just peat and clay.

Location doesn't allow permanent building foundations (concrete slap) and is logistically challenging(everything needs to be carried there by hand) so screw-pile seems like a great option just need to figure out how many I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay a local engineering firm, that will be familiar with the local requirements, typical bearing capacity of those soils, etc.

The fact that you are on old seafloor (but not underwater) is a testament to the overall quality of engineering in the Netherlands ;-)